# How to write simple sign-in & authorize Rest with Keycloak?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

Doing project with spring boot & keycloack.
want to know how to make elementary sign-in & authorize Rest with Keycloak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't write sign-in. You just redirect users to Keycloak authorize endpoint (with a redirect URL parameter). Once the user logged-in on Keycloak, he'll be redirected back to client (at redirect URL) with an authorization-code to exchange for tokens (access and maybe refresh and ID tokens).

Do not write all that yourself, use an OIDC client library and setup one of those two scenario:

- you are OK with the browser accessing tokens (not quite the trend lately), then make the "rich" browser ap a public OAuth2 client ([angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) is a sample lib for Angular, just choose one for your client framework)
- you don't want the tokens to leave your servers, then implement th **B**ackend **F**or **F**rontend pattern. Spring-cloud-gateway can be configured for that purpose (I am elaborating [a tutorial on that subject](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff)), but it is not the only option.

To authorize requests on REST API, you configure it as a resource-server. [Tutorials there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials).